# Opencart - XML to MySQL - manufacturer not assigned to products

Tags: php, mysql, xml, opencart

I just finished to import all the products in my **Opencart** installation via a script that imports all the data from an XML file that the supplier gave me. All data was correctly imported, even the manufacturers, but these were not assigned to each product.

Basically, the product page in FO does not feature the manufacturer, since in the mysql field the manufacturer ID is missing.

The script imported the manufacturers, and each has its own correct ID. I can manually set for each product the correct manufacturer, but since we are talking of more than 5300 products, it is not the correct way to go.

How can I assign the correct manufacturer to the correct product, knowing the manufacturer_id and the complete product information?

Comment: If there is a link between the product and the manufacturer in the original XML file, simply loop over it again, select the product's manufacturer, then look it up in DB and retrieve it's ID. Then look up the product in the DB and update it's manufacturer's ID with the one you have just retrieved.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to fix the issue with the help of the programmer who made the script.